# sed command deleting content in the whole range while respecting the condition

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sed, command

There is a file of similar format:

```
# Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
# Donec vitae ex metus. Integer nec dui sit amet odio vehicula tincidunt ac eget justo.
#
[A8-LINER-ADJUSTEMENT]
type: q-first-party
id: 3.4.987
canOperate: true
hash: 9bf533ef77fddb43cdc4b96ca9eb68fc862d71e90bb05b98abc9d1050893c266

[A8-LINER-ADJUSTEMENT]
type: q-first-party
id: 5.2.987
canOperate: true
hash: c8939c165c3af4ae77e7d5030b43644721fb8225e2994e846ef129f7de49254b

[A8-LINER-ADJUSTEMENT]
type: q-third-party
id: 4.9.987
canOperate: false
hash: f9ddaeaad5ed2280fbb9660553ab0af8bf6ea0a5a4b0db432398f26470e557bf
```

The goal is to delete whole content between `[A8-LINER-ADJUSTEMENT]` (inclusive) and empty line (inclusive). While property `type` is `q-third-party`.

File after the command execution should be looking like this:

```
# Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
# Donec vitae ex metus. Integer nec dui sit amet odio vehicula tincidunt ac eget justo.
#
[A8-LINER-ADJUSTEMENT]
type: q-first-party
id: 3.4.987
canOperate: true
hash: 9bf533ef77fddb43cdc4b96ca9eb68fc862d71e90bb05b98abc9d1050893c266

[A8-LINER-ADJUSTEMENT]
type: q-first-party
id: 5.2.987
canOperate: true
hash: c8939c165c3af4ae77e7d5030b43644721fb8225e2994e846ef129f7de49254b
```

`sed -i '/\[A8-LINER-ADJUSTEMENT\]/,/^$/ { /q-third-party/d; }' introduction-availe.dat`

This command deletes only `type: q-third-party` lines as the removal of the content within the specified range was expected.

Comment: This is difficult to do with `sed`, because the condition is after the first line to match. Can you use something else instead? `perl` or `awk` would be better.

Comment: Are those lines starting with `#` at the top of the file associated with the file as a whole or with the first block of data in the file? Should they always be printed or should they only be printed if the first block of data is to be printed? Do you have other such `#`-started lines in your input and, if so, how should we know whether to print those or not on a case-by-case basis? Can any such lines appear inside a block of data, either on a line of it's own or at the start/middle/end of a line?

Comment: Printing the blocks you want is trivial, it's knowing when to print those `#`-started lines (presumably comments but idk) that is the only tricky thing about what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you don't have `[` characters outside he tags, you can create an ugly `sed` solution

```
sed -z 's/\[A8-LINER-ADJUSTEMENT\][^[]*type: q-third-party[^[]*//g' file
```

The `[^[]*` is a set of characters `[]`, with everything except a `[`, so `^[`, repeated 0 or more times `*`.

Answer (score 2):

Using `awk`:

```
awk 'BEGIN{RS=""; ORS="\n\n"}/type: q-first-party/' file
```

Yields:

```
# Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
# Donec vitae ex metus. Integer nec dui sit amet odio vehicula tincidunt ac eget justo.
#
[A8-LINER-ADJUSTEMENT]
type: q-first-party
id: 3.4.987
canOperate: true
hash: 9bf533ef77fddb43cdc4b96ca9eb68fc862d71e90bb05b98abc9d1050893c266 


[A8-LINER-ADJUSTEMENT]
type: q-first-party
id: 5.2.987
canOperate: true
hash: c8939c165c3af4ae77e7d5030b43644721fb8225e2994e846ef129f7de49254b
```

Answer (score 1):

Just for fun .. If you have `PHP` installed on your server .. This will do the trick .. There is 1001 ways to do this programmatically .. I just chose PHP because of it's ease of use with `explode()`

Basically we deconstruct the file into your primary elements (an array of), then deconstruct those further into secondary elements of an array().  Then we check the index `[1]` for your `type: q-third-party` string and reconstruct the file if it contains that string, then save the file.

```
<?php

$file = file_get_contents("introduction-availe.dat");
$items = explode('[', $file);
$file_header = $items[0];
array_shift($items);

$new_file = "$file_header\n";
foreach($items as $item){
   $item = '[' . $item;
   $sub_items = array_filter( explode("\n", $item) );
   if($sub_items[1] != 'type: q-third-party'){
      foreach($sub_items as $sub_item){
         $new_file .= "$sub_item\n";
      }
      $new_file .= "\n";
   }
}

$f=fopen('introduction-availe.dat','w');
fwrite($f,$new_file);
fclose($f);
```